# What is the actual difference between $project and $group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have read the docs and still not quite following it. According to it, it returns me specific documents according to my own specifications inside a collection. For grouping, it pretty much says the same thing: "Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping"

So, what does this following code is actually doing? It seems redundant to me.

```
BillingCycle.aggregate([{
    $project: {credit: {$sum: "$credits.value"}, debt: {$sum: "debts.value"}}

}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        credit: {$sum: "$credit"}, debt: {$sum: "debt"}
    }
}, {
    $project: {_id: 0, credit: 1, debt: 1   }
}]});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping"

The purpose of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is not only to push some fields to next stage but to gather some element on the basis of input criteria passed in the `_id` attribute.

On the other, hand [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) function will exclude/include some field(or custom field) to next stage. As per document you can see the definition *"Passes along the documents with the requested fields to the next stage in the pipeline. The specified fields can be existing fields from the input documents or newly computed fields."*

There is one case if we suppress the `_id` from `$group` then it will calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole. Which seems to act like `$project`.

For the query on $project stage is redundant

```
BillingCycle.aggregate([ {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        credit: {$sum: "$credit.value"}, debt: {$sum: "debt.value"}
    }
}, {
    $project: {_id: 0, credit: 1, debt: 1   }
}]});
```